# Variance condition for Stationarity of AR(p)

Tags: time-series, variance, stationarity, autoregressive

I have noticed on Wiki: *for an AR(p) model to be wide-sense stationary, the roots of the polynomial $1-\sum_{n=1}^p \phi_i B^n$ must lie outside the unit circle*.

Also, stationarity also implies covariance function depends only on the difference between $t_i$ and $t_j$ , so the variance should be a constant. Then we could calculate the variance as: $\frac {\sigma^2_\epsilon}{1-\sum_{n=1}^p \phi_i^2}$. If we look at the denominator, it should be positive, So why don't we require $1-\sum_{n=1}^p \phi_i^2 >0$? Is it implied by the condition that all roots must lie outside the unit circle?